# Is downregulation of neurological receptors fully reversible, i.e. complete upregulation and resensitization?

Tags: molecular-biology, neurology, receptor, psychoneuropharmacology, benzodiazepine

Are down/upregulation truly reciprocal mechanisms? After a binding ligand or agonist is removed, such as a prescription medication, is upregulation and resensitization able to occur to a level that exactly equates to and completely reverse and fully make up for any loss of receptors, bonding affinity, etc? Could anything theoretically be permanent? Does time/length of prescription play any role in this, including when prescribed a benzodiazepine (Clonazepam)?